# Control caret position with TcxCustomEdit in delphi

Tags: delphi, onkeypress

How should I control my caret position with TcxCustomeEdit in Delphi, I'm currently using KeyPress event to control my inputs, every four letters I enter, there will be able to show a '-' in the string, and i able to make it happen, yet every time a '-' shows up, my caret move back to front. How should I make caret locate at the end of my string?

Below is my code:-

```
procedure Trlblfrmcourierpercelarmtn.MyColumnKeyPress(
Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
AEdit: TcxCustomEdit; var Key: Char);
var
str : string;
j : integer;
begin
inherited;
if AEdit.EditingValue <> null then
begin
  str := AEdit.EditingValue;
    if (str <> '')  then
    begin
      j := str.Length;
      if ((j  + 1) mod 5 = 0) then
      begin
        str := str + '-';
      end;
      AEdit.EditValue:= str;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Well, don't you want to rather use `TcxMaskEdit` for your task? Modifying user input might be confusing.

Comment: Hi Victoria, due to user's requirement, I have to input all the data into Dbgrid instead.

Comment: I see, but using mask edit doesn't change that requirement. It can help you with your task and can make the user input less confusing. If you'll give it a try, read about grid column's `Properties` property (specifically `MaskEdit` value and related stuff).

Comment: I don't know the `TcxCustomEdit` component, but if it behaves similar as the `Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit`, add after the line `AEdit.EditValue:= str;`, a new line: `AEdit.SelStart := j+1;`. That should move the caret to the end of the entered text.

Comment: @Victoria mask edit will also unable to fulfill the requirement ,  because sometimes the data we key-in  are not the same length.

Comment: @TomBrunberg thanks for your advice, yet TcxCustomEdit does not behave like Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit, it does not have the method of SelStart,  if TcxCustomEdit have a method of SelStart, I can use SelSelection instead.  But it doesn't

Comment: Try to access it like `(AEdit as TcxTextEdit).SelStart := ...;`.

Comment: @Victoria but I already declared AEdit as TcxCustomEdit in my parameter for MyColumnKeyPress procedure

Comment: Yes, but `TcxCustomEdit` does not publish `SelStart` property (typecasting to `TcxCustomTextEdit`, or `TcxTextEdit` would allow you to access it). Look at [this thread](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/CQ52591/how-to-access-the-inplace-editor-s-selstart-and-sellength-properties).

Comment: @Victoria Thanks, man!　It works!!  Thank you so much for your guidance!

Comment: You're very welcome! :) Though I still believe that mask edit would be better (the one from DevExpress supports even regex).

Comment: @Victoria  Noted with thanks

Comment: **if it behaves like a TEdit** do it like this: use the onChange event and each time the user types a letter you scan the input text (not letter the hall text) and remove the special character (i.e '-') then you reorder the text again where you will add '-' each four letters. then at last you set the caret position to the end.